# Links on Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, hyperlink

I am using react to create a chrome extension but link functionality doesn't seems to be working on the extension popup

```
<a
          href={`https://google.com`}
        >
          <Button>Click here</Button>
 </a>
```

Comment: what happens when you click? Does it work without the <Button> component?

Comment: Add `target=_blank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding `target="_blank"` on the link tag would resolve this issue